# Get last day in quarter

Tags: r

I have a sequence of dates and each date has a value

```
dat = data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2016/8/1"), "days"), value =seq(1, length(seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2016/8/1"), "days")),1 ))
```

I'd like to subset the dataframe and return the last day in the quarter with a value

So for that dates above the results should be

```
2015-03-31    90
2015-06-30   181
2015-09-30   273
2015-12-31   365
2016-03-31   456
2016-06-30   547
2016-08-01   579
```

Comment: What is your reference date? `2015-01-01`? Have a look at [that](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/lubridate/man/quarter.html)

Comment: https://www.google.com/?client=ubuntu#channel=fs&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+[r]+last+day+of+quarter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's just one way

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dat %>% 
  group_by(quarter=quarter(date, T)) %>% 
  filter(date==max(date)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-quarter)
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#         date value
#       <date> <dbl>
# 1 2015-03-31    90
# 2 2015-06-30   181
# 3 2015-09-30   273
# 4 2015-12-31   365
# 5 2016-03-31   456
# 6 2016-06-30   547
# 7 2016-08-01   579
```

Comment: I get this error Error in max(date) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument when I run the code

Comment: I think dat %>% 
  group_by(quarter=quarter(date, T)) %>% 
  summarise(m = max(date)) will work

Comment: You got the error when using your sample data?